# NOT IN vs. NOTEXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why would the first query return 0 rows but the second query return rows?

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.GW_ASO_SCRUBBED
WHERE  ACCOUNT_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT Acct_num
                              FROM   dbo.ACCOUNT_X_MASTER)

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.GW_ASO_SCRUBBED s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Acct_num
                   FROM   dbo.ACCOUNT_X_MASTER M
                   WHERE  s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = M.ACCT_NUM)
```

Comment: Because `Acct_num` contains a `NULL`

Comment: This post has a good explanation if Acct_num has nulls then Not In won't work the same way as Not exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: That was exactly it. Plz eply and I will mark the answer correct. :-) Thx

Comment: It's already answered in the possible duplicate.

Comment: @ChadD No need, we already have an answer. an answer that simply links to another Stack Overflow question is subject to being deleted. The good way to handle it is just mark this question as a duplicate.